# Is there any way by which we get the information if any particular user adds any Q/A.

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, notifications

> 1. For the last few days I found that [user134824](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/134824/user134824) is dealing with problems which are of my interest. Few more users are there who frequently deals with problems which are of my interest. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794511/let-a-1-ldots-a-100-be-100-positive-integers-show-that-for-some-m/794513#794513) the answer of user134824 is very fundamental.
> 2. Some of the users are very advanced and asks very tough problems, I'm a high school student so these questions are tough for me(not of my use at my level), some users ask fundamental problems and some users are there who frequently deal with the problems of particular topic (say elementary-number-system), I'm also learning the same topic.

**My question is that is there any way by which I add some users to my account on SE so that any question or answer posted by that user comes to my inbox.**

Comment: On the "Activity" tab of their profile, at the bottom, there's a link where you can get the (RSS) [user feed](http://math.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/134824).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you Sir. It works but is there not any way by which I directly get the information in my inbox on SE. for example when I get an answer of my problem then I get a message in the inbox. Can same happen with what I'm asking.

Comment: Not that I know of. And I don't expect there is, since SE is not intended to be a social network, so "following a user" functionality is intentionally mostly absent.

Comment: Related: [Friends lists — keeping track of users](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/friends-lists-keeping-track-of-users)